# Property injector in controller and dbcontext

Tags: autofac

I'm have my `BaseController`, and have a `property` `RunTimeContext`

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public IRunTimeContext RunTimeContext {get;set;}

}
```

my method `OnActionExecuting` using `RunTimeContext`

```
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
     _logRequest = new LogRequest
      {
        TenantId = RunTimeContext.TenantId
      }
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

But, my `RunTimeContext` is ever `null`

My autofac configuration is:

```
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
  builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

  builder.RegisterType<RunTimeContext>().As<IRunTimeContext>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.PropertiesAutowired()` to your controllers registration, not to your `RunTimeContext` type registration, as you want controller's property to be set, not `RunTimeContext`:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: all public property will instanced? No need to contructor. I can not make an exception only in some implementations?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you doubts, but you do not have to register all controllers with `RegisterControllers` method, you can do it manually, controller by controller using `RegisterType`, and use `PropertiesAutowired()` only on controllers you need. With `PropertiesAutowired()` all properties with types registered in container would be instantiated. You can also wire only properties you want, but it would also require some additional custom code for every controller, like use `OnActivating` event (http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/events.html#onactivating)